# Tomcat 8.5.37 failling to run application with Open JDK 8.u192 from AdoptOpenJDK in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, openjdk

I was using the Oracle JDK but to avoid license issues I'm migrating to OpenJDK.
I've opted for Windows AdoptOpenJdk 8_192, but I'm having some issues when running it with Tomcat 8.5 in Eclipse (this only happens when running with Tomcat, desktop Java Applications runs correctly).

The Tomcat console output is as follows:

```
    com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2256)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:204)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:736)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:762)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:89)
    at org.omnifaces.util.BeansLocal.getReference(BeansLocal.java:104)
    at org.omnifaces.util.BeansLocal.getReference(BeansLocal.java:92)
    at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:115)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.getInstance(EagerBeansRepository.java:66)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.instantiateApplicationScopedAndRegisterListenerIfNecessary(EagerBeansRepository.java:78)
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:647)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1847)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:703)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:303)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$100(ClientProxyProvider.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(ClientProxyProvider.java:52)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    ... 25 more
```

I'd like to know how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the correct answer for my question but it solved: 
before I was using the OpenJDK from AdoptOpenJDK with the OpenJ9 JVM, so I changed to the Hotspot version and it worked.

Maybe there is some incompatibility between Tomcat 8 and OpenJ9 JVM.